# nonnegative superharmonic function, constant

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> *Exercise:* Let $u \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be superharmonic ($- \Delta u \ge 0$) and nonnegative with $u(0)=0$. Show that $u=0$.

Hello,

I want to use the *strong max principle*. The problem ist that I can't use it for $\mathbb{R}^n$ because I need a bounded space for u to apply it. On every compact connected subset $K$, containing $0$, $u$ must be constant $\min_{x\in K} u(x)$ and so $u=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove $u=0$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ it is enough to prove $u=0$ on $B_r(0)$ for each $r>0$, because each point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is in some such ball. Your idea achieves exactly this, because $0$ is in the interior of such sets, and by the assumptions it is necessarily an interior minimum point.

Comment: But where i need that u is a nonnegative function?

Comment: @LaurenVeganer In order to know that $0$ is an interior minimum point: you have $u(0)=0$ and $u(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$...

Comment: @LaurenVeganer Here I am really using the minimum principle, not the mean value property.

Comment: I always confuse those two. Thanks for your help.